# Warning on my messages from Gmail when sending email with PHPMailer

Tags: email, phpmailer, sendmail

I need help in this troubleshoot with sending mail with phpmailer.
I try to send mail with PHPmailer v6 and everything is working fine, but when I receive the message on gmail i get RED MARK warning on the message that says:

```
This message appears dangerous
This message may contain unsafe content as many people have identified similar messages as phishing scams. So avoid clicking on links, downloading attachments, or responding with any personal information.
```

I really dont know the reason for this message and this is the code i use in my script:

```
$link ="<a href='".$setting['site_url']."?v=".$rand."'>".$setting['site_url']."?v=".$rand."</a>";
$mes='Hello,<br><br> Thank you for registering at '.$setting['faucet_name'].'. However, before you getting running on the site, you\'ve to confirm your email address.<br> Click here:  <b>'.$link.'</b><br> to confirm your account, or copy the link below directly to confirm your email address.<br><br> Regards,<br> '.$setting['faucet_name'].'<br><br><small>If you didn\'t apply for an account, please ignore this email and you won\'t be bugged again.</small>';

    $from='no-reply@'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom($from, $setting['faucet_name']);
    $mail->addAddress($email, $username);                 
    // Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                 
    $mail->Subject = 'Confirm your account at '.$setting['faucet_name'];
    $mail->Body    = $mes;
    $mail->AltBody = 'please use HTML viewer to see the message';

    if($mail->send()){
    $stmt= $db->prepare("INSERT INTO verify_user(username,email,password,ref,verify_key,created)VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?) ");
    $stmt->bind_param("sssssi",$username,$email,$password,$ref,$rand,$time);
    $stmt->execute();
    echo json_encode(array('success' =>'Message sent!'));
} else {
    echo json_encode(array('success' => "Message could not be sent."));
}
```

Comment: Look at the headers of the received message on gmail; it will often tell you why a message caused problems. Add them to your question and we can help diagnose it.

Comment: this is from help center in gmail:"This message could be a scam" warning
You'll see this warning above any email that looks like a scam, but comes from an address in your Gmail contacts list.

Comment: Yes, you already said that. We need to see what the headers say as it may tell us *why* they think that.

Answer (score 0):

Although I am not sure, I'd say that the issue is not in your code.

Most probably this comes from the content of the mail itself, exactly as Gmail says. Its algorithms estimated based on some criteria that your email resembles a lot emails sent usually by phishers. So it warns you about this mail in your inbox.

Comment: this warring appears when i add a link to the mail , and i also tried many ways to change the mail content , but always get this warning , i searched a lot before share the question and i feel that the problem in setFrom() field maybe this field is not correct and made gmail filter suspected the email , do you have any idea about setFrom() field